# Failing to open csv file

Tags: python, csv

My current python script is like this:

```
import csv

with open ('2017_IL_sales.csv','r') as infile:
    reader=csv.reader(infile)
    with open('2017_IL_sales_report.csv') as outfile:
        writer=csv.writer(outfile)
        dict_report={rows[1]:rows[2] for rows in reader}

print dict_report
```

In brief, I want to open a csv file called `2017_IL_sales` then create a dictionary for two columns inside. But with whatever reason, everytime I run the code via IDLE it told me this `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2017_IL_sales.csv'`. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: The error sounds descriptive, is the file in the same path as the script being run?

Comment: yes, they are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the script you are running is in the same folder as the file you are trying to read. If that is not possible, make sure to specify the correct file path.

Comment: I put the script and the csv file in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Is IDLE's working directory that folder?

Run this in IDLE and see what you get:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```